# How can I use chenupt/SpringIndicator in Fragment

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragmentmanager

I want to use it in a v4.Fragment to load childFragment, and the [SpringIndicator](https://github.com/chenupt/SpringIndicator) sample code based on [MultipleModel](https://github.com/chenupt/MultipleModel).
I tryed to deliver a ChildFragmentManager to ModelPagerAdapter in Fragment follow this:

```
ModelPagerAdapter adapter = new ModelPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), new PagerModelManager());
```

But that not works, nothing displayed on phone's screen.
Actually,The SpringIndicator will works in a Activity.(use getSupportFragmentManager as the arg)
How can I do?Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry,everyBody.That code in question taked effect but not display beacause of background color.So, You can use SpringIndicator in Fragment to load childFragment with:

```
ModelPagerAdapter adapter = new ModelPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), new PagerModelManager());
```

The first arg is getChildFragmentManager() worked for me.